# Working with empty(NULL) int datatypes in sql server

Tags: sql

How to select an int datatype field(bonus) which is inserted as NULL?

Tried the following but prints nothing though there is a valid entry.

```
select e_name from employee, payroll where datepart(year,hire_date)=2005 and employee.e#=payroll.e# and bonus=null
```

also if i want to add another year say 2007 to be checked with 2005 using or, what is the query for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When testing for null, you must use this syntax:

```
... 
and bonus is null
```

FYI the syntax for testing if *not* null is `bonus is not null`.

All other comparisons (eg =, <, like, etc) will return false with a null value.